# Same animation Multiple Times using animate.css

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I am trying to pull the following along. Please Help.

The requirement is to use:
1. Animate.css
2. jquery-1.10.1.min.js

From the Animate.css only the expand open animation needs to be used. The requirement is for a watch store at my local. They want their clients to be able to try the watch on their hand (something similar to www.lenskart.com effect).

I am able to run the code as described below, for only one animation (i.e. expandOpen) at a time on the same page.

The page is to be designed in the fashion shown in the image: [image: Page Setup]

There are multiple watches to be displayed, as in the image. The effect of expandOpen needs to be implemented on each watch in order to try them on the wrist.

Currently, when I want to try a watch (say the 1st one) it animates perfectly. But when i want to animate the second watch, it doesnt work.

I would appreciate any help on getting the same effect of expandOpen implemented on akll the buttons, possibly without page refresh.

My HTML code is:
{

```
<section id="animation">
        <div class="animation-container">
            <div id="object" class="animate"></div>
            <img src="images/hand_watches.png" />
        </div>
    </section>

    <section id="actions">
        <div class="container">
            <h2>Try the Watch</h2>
            <a href="#" id="expandOpenBtn" class="button"><img src="images/watch1.png"><br>Try Me!</a>          
            <a href="#" id="expandOpenBtn" class="button"><img src="images/watch1.png"><br>Try Me!</a>          
            <a href="#" id="expandOpenBtn" class="button"><img src="images/watch1.png"><br>Try Me!</a>          
            <a href="#" id="expandOpenBtn" class="button"><img src="images/watch1.png"><br>Try Me!</a>          
            <a href="#" id="expandOpenBtn" class="button"><img src="images/watch1.png"><br>Try Me!</a>          
        </div>
    </section>

    <script>
        $('#expandOpenBtn').click(function() {
            $(this).each(function(){
                    $('#object').removeClass('animate expandOpen');             
                    $('#object').addClass("animate expandOpen");
                });
        }); 
    </script>
```

}

CSS Code is for animation is:
{

```
.expandOpen{
    animation-name: expandOpen;
    -webkit-animation-name: expandOpen; 

    animation-duration: 1.2s;   
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.2s;

    animation-timing-function: ease-out;    
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;    

    visibility: visible !important; 
}

@keyframes expandOpen {
    0% {
        transform: scale(1.8);      
    }
    50% {
        transform: scale(0.95);
    }   
    80% {
        transform: scale(1.05);
    }
    90% {
        transform: scale(0.98);
    }   
    100% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }           
}

@-webkit-keyframes expandOpen {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.8);      
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.95);
    }   
    80% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
    }
    90% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.98);
    }   
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    }                   
}
```

}

jQuery Used is:
jQuery v1.10.1.js

Images used:
1. Hand [image: Hand to try watch on]
2. [image: Watch]

The person should be able to click one watch and see it expandOpen on the wrist displayed. And should be able to do this multiple times.

Comment: is my question not clear??? or am i asking something which is actually simple??? but the problem is O can not figure it out!!!

Comment: I only want to use the same animation on all the buttons that i have created. Please suggest me a way!!!